# jq : how to extract attribute value from JSON conditionally

Tags: javascript, node.js, jq

I'm trying to extract all the IDs (`id`) of objects without the `contentType` attribute from the following `JSON`:

```
    {
       "version":"1.5.0",
       "metadata":{
          "version":"1.5.0",
          "createdOn":"2023-01-01"
       },
       "fileId":"1",
       "CanBeAnyName":[
          {
             "id":"BT-02",
             "contentType":"file",
             "readOnly":true
          },
          {
             "id":"BT-03",
             "readOnly":true
          }
       ],
       "AlsoCanBeAnyName":[
          {
             "id":"BT",
             "contentType":"empty"
          },
          {
             "contentType":"group",
             "content":[
                {
                   "id":"BT-Care",
                   "_repeatable":true,
                   "content":[
                      {
                         "id":"BT-90-care",
                         "contentType":"group",
                         "content":[
                            {
                               "id":"GR-300-analyze",
                               "contentType":"field"
                            },
                            {
                               "id":"BT-10"
                            }
                         ]
                      }
                   ]
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
```

The jq command I'm using at the moment is:

```
walk(if (type == "object" and .id) then if ((.id | startswith("BT")) and has("contentType") | not) then .id else empty end else . end)
```

Result:

```
    {
      "version": "1.5.0",
      "metadata": {
        "version": "1.5.0",
        "createdOn": "2023-01-01"
      },
      "fileId": "1",
      "CanBeAnyName": [
        "BT-03"
      ],
      "AlsoCanBeAnyName": [
        {
          "contentType": "group",
          "content": [
            "BT-Care"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Expected result:

`["BT-03", "BT-Care"]` or even better to iterate down in the nested object `["BT-03", "BT-Care", "BT-10"]`

How can I achieve this, please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could traverse the document tree using `..`, filter for `objects`, and `select` by all your filters. Wrap that in array brackets to get an array.

```bash
[.. | objects | select(
  (has("contentType") | not) and has("id") and (.id | startswith("BT"))
).id]
```

```json
[
  "BT-03",
  "BT-Care",
  "BT-10"
]
```

Use the `-c` flag to have the array printed in one single line: `["BT-03","BT-Care","BT-10"]`